# cannot change the favorite icon color when pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the favorite icon and its color when pressed

```
class MyFavorite extends ChangeNotifier{


  bool isFavorite ;

  isFavorited(){
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

```
var favorite = Provider.of<MyFavorite>(context , listen: false);
```

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {

                        favorite.isFavorited();
                      },
                      child:  Icon(favorite.isFavorite == true ? Icons.favorite :Icons.favorite_border, color: favorite.isFavorite == true ? Colors.red : Colors.white, 
                      )),
```

and when I try to set the listen to true when I clicked
the color changed for other items

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need/should do. First, you need to give the boolean an initial value. Secondly, it is advised to modify your properties as *getters*, but in doing so, it then makes sense to make them private first(indicated by the underscore). This is recommended so that they will not be able to be accessed from outside and modified. Lastly, you need to take off the `listen: false` because you are actually trying to change the UI by rebuilding the widget.

```
 bool _isFavorite = false;
  
 bool get isFav => _isFavorite;

  isFavorited(){
    _isFavorite = !_isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

> 

```
var favorite = Provider.of<MyFavorite>(context);
```

> 

```
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {

                   favorite.isFavorited();
                   },
                      child:  Icon(favorite.isFav == true ? Icons.favorite :Icons.favorite_border, color: favorite.isFav == true ? Colors.red : Colors.white, 
                      )),
enter code here
```

As noted in the comments, you can just use `favorite.isFav` for the condition without the `== true`

I highly reccomend you to read this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: What do you mean by "you are calling the function, instead of the actual boolean"? Additionally, `favorite.isFav == true` can be shortened to just `favorite.isFav`.

Comment: You are right. I thought I saw `favorite.isFavorited` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `isFavourite` variable in the class as `true` or `false`.
like this:-

```
class MyFavorite extends ChangeNotifier{


  bool isFavorite =false;

  isFavorited(){
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Put this line in the `build` function (if it's not already there) and remove the `listen: false`

`var favorite = Provider.of<MyFavorite>(context);`

`listen:false` meaning you don't want to listen for upcoming changes.